# Missing host in redirect from Fabric8 V2 console to OAuth

Tags: fabric8

I'm trying out Fabric8 V2 on OpenShift V3 using Docker (version 1.5, native install, on Ubuntu 14.04).

I've followed the guide at http://fabric8.io/v2/openShiftDocker.html and used `bash <(curl -sSL https://bit.ly/get-fabric8) -k` to setup everything.

At the end of the procedure, a new tab opens in browser at `http://172.30.17.152/kubernetes/overview` which is immediately redirected to an OAuth page, but the URL is incomplete (missing the host part and possibly a port number).

The URL was: `https://oauth/authorize?client_id=fabric8-console&response_type=token&state=http%3A%2F%2F172.30.17.152%2Fkubernetes%2Foverview&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F172.30.17.152%2Fkubernetes%2Foverview`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version. We hack on the code daily.

Comment: I have a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

This question is obsolete. Please try with a newer release.